# Convert large arrays in pandas dataframe to large numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dateframe that has a column that looks like this:

```
0         [  [    1051,    0,    10181,    62,    17,   ...
1         [  [    882,    0,    9909,    59,    23,    9...
2         [  [    1061,    0,    10192,    60,    17,   ...
3         [  [    122,    4,    501,    2,    8,    3,  ...
4         [  [    397,    1,    859,    9,    8,    5,  ...
5         [  [    1213,    1,    10791,    23,    17,   ...
6         [  [    1395,    3,    11147,    0,    17,    ...
7         [  [    757,    3,    1900,    34,    23,    8...
8         [  [    129,    0,    507,    10,    8,    3, ...
9         [  [    1438,    0,    11177,    26,    2,    ...
10        [  [    1272,    1,    10901,    7,    17,    ...
```

An example row with fewer features would be something like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
```

The datatype is a string so `json.loads` has to be used to convert them to arrays that are [N_TIMESTAMPS, N_FEATURES] where each feature is a numerical value.

In order to use this data as input for a neural network I have to convert this column into a numpy array of shape: [N_SAMPLES, N_TIMESTAMPS, N_FEATURES]. So, like this:

```
[[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]]
```

This is how I am doing it now:

```
train_x = np.array(
   df.time_stream.apply(json.loads).apply(np.array).apply(
      lambda x: x.reshape(N_TIMESTAMPS,N_FEATURES).tolist()).values.tolist()
 )
```

For a dataset that has 268,521 rows, this computation takes 12.5 mins. Not ideal, but it was working; however, it's not scalable. For the new dataset with 756,961 rows it never finishes (N_TIMESTAMPS = 100; N_FEATURES = 54) because it uses up all of the RAM and the computer crashes.

I'm looking for recommendations for how to make this faster, and perhaps more memory efficient. One issue is that a lot of swap is being used.

Comment: Not sure how much it'll save you but `df.time_stream.apply(lambda x: np.array(json.loads(x)).reshape(N_TIMESTAMPS,N_FEATURES)).values` seems to give you the same result as what you have, with somewhat less unnecessary calculation. Also, might it be worthwhile to do it in stages?

Comment: Can you give a small example that we can run in our REPLs? Calling `tolist()` will *always* be hard on memory

Comment: @JoshFriedlander It does take 1/3 of the time removing the tolist, but the final shape is not what I need. It produces an array of shape (268521,) and I am not able to reshape it to (268521,N_TIMESTAMPS, N_FEATURES).

Comment: What's the actual source of the data before you read it into a Pandas dataframe? The whole idea of reading strings line-by-line into pandas and then using a json parser seems inefficient. Maybe you can use `numpy.loadtxt` directly from the source file, skipping Pandas and json.

Comment: @w-m It's a csv file. The csv file is produced in Python from a pandas dataframe that is loaded via an SQL query on a Snowflake DB. The arrays are constructed in the query using array_construct (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html)

Comment: My intuition is that these are too many steps using not the most efficient representations (string of list of arrays in csv). Ideally tackle this at the very beginning, and go right from the returned SQL data to some form of file format that can be directly read by numpy. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Snowflake DB. Maybe you can ask a question for how to go from the SQL returned data (give examples) directly to numpy.